# How to say protractor to wait till page loads?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, automation, jasmine, protractor

My application taking some to page the login page.So protractor trying to enter the user name before page loads.So i need to say protractor to wait till the login page loads.

Could you please help me what command I need to use for this and where I need to use?(Please modify my code to add the wait command)

***PFB for my onPrepare and beforeeach function***

```
onPrepare: function() {  
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({

})
}

beforeEach(function() {
       browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/');
       //browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30000);
       //browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
        //browser.sleep( 10000 );
        //browser.waitForAngular();
  });
```

I used those commented functions,but it didn't work for me.

Please guide me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to click the `Get Started` button, [wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for the button to become [clickable](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.elementToBeClickable):

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var getStarted = element(by.css('button[title="Get started"]'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(getStarted), 5000);
getStarted.click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the wait command: **browser.driver.wait(condition, timeout);**

```
onPrepare: function() {  
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
    });
}

beforeEach(function() {
       browser.driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/');
       return browser.driver.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function (url) {
                return url.indexOf('https://accounts.google.com/') > -1;
            });
        }, 5000);
        //whatever you want after
  });
```

you can wait for any condition like that.
Also, google f.e is not an angular page, so you should use:
**browser.driver.get** instead of protractors **browser.get**,
or it will wait for angular on the page.